# How to host a HTTPS server with a valid certificate in Node.js using HTTPS library

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, nodejs-server

I want to host my own https server, but the certificate I have generated is not valid, and when accessing from broswers it says insecure connection.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either implement it in your NodeJS code base or go with `http proxy` using `Nginx` or `Apache`

Using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15313480):

> ````js
> http = require("http");
>
> var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem').toString(); var
> certificate = fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem').toString();
>
> var credentials = crypto.createCredentials({key: privateKey, cert:
> certificate});
>
> var handler = function (req, res) {   res.writeHead(200,
> {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});   res.end('Hello World\n'); };
>
> var server = http.createServer(); server.setSecure(credentials);
> server.addListener("request", handler); server.listen(8000); ```
> ````

It's recommended using the Nginx method

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Add the SSL files in the Vhost

If you want to go with a free SSL try certbot, it will auto-install SSL in the vhost

https://certbot.eff.org/